# GitLab CI - :image needed if runner runs on a vm with pre-installed docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm wondering that most of tutorials for the configuration of `.gitlab-ci.yml` use the `image: docker` or `image: docker/compose`.

In my case we have a pre-installed docker and docker-compose on our virtual machine (Linux).

1. So is it necessary to use a `image` definition?
2. In other cases they often use the `dind` (Docker-in-Docker) functionality, is that necessary in my case?
3. If not, when do i use it/is it useful?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. So is it necessary to use a image definition?

No, as mentioned in "[Using Docker images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html)"

GitLab CI/CD in conjunction with [GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html) can use [Docker Engine](https://www.docker.com/) to test and build any application.

> When used with GitLab CI/CD, Docker runs each job in a separate and isolated container using the predefined image that’s set up in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

So you can use any image you need for your job to run.

> 2. In other cases they often use the dind (Docker-in-Docker) functionality, is that necessary in my case?
>    3. If not, when do i use it/is it useful?

As documented in "[Building Docker images with GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) ", this is needed if your job is to build a docker image (as opposed to use an existing docker image)